# How to deactivate header files duplication in SCons?

Tags: python, scons

In my build I am required to copy header files in a flat structure while source code files are copied in a hierachical structure.

By default when specifying `duplicate = 1` (my build is a variant dir build) in SCons all header files and .c/.cpp files are duplicated in a hierarchical structure.

Is there a way to deactivate duplication of header files ?

What I tried until now:

To provide an empty list to CPPPATH.

To remove source scanners from my builders.

I want to install them by myself in a separate folder. I don't want to turn off duplication since I need that for .c/.cpp files.

Comment: Why do you need duplication for your c files?  If you use variantdir it will reference them where they are, and then output the object files in the specified variant dirs..

Comment: I need that because of some static analysis tools. The analysis is performed on the files that should be compiled. I am still thinking how to suppress command execution for the first time using scons but this is another question.

Comment: try: -n, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon
No execute. Print the commands that would be executed to build any out-of-date target files, but do not execute the commands.  (take a look at the man page.. http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't turn off the `duplicate` method for only a subset of files (based on their extension for example).

Installing a subset of source and target files to a specific directory is usually handled by calling the `Install()` method. Independent of whether you plan to use `duplicate=0` or `duplicate=1` for your actual builds, I'd suggest to not interfere with what happens in the variant dirs...and just letting SCons do its thing.